# Permission denied while save a file in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-permissions, android-file, android-external-storage

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am saving a bitmap as file. But it is throwing permission denied exception even if I set the right permissions in the manifest file.

This is how I save a bitmap as a file

```
private void downloadImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        try{
            String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpeg";
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);

            if(file.exists()){
                file.delete();
            }

            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);


            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Image saved to your device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

When I save, it is toasting me error like this.

[image]

These are all the permissions I set in manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Why is that error throwing? How can I correct my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it)

Comment: `file.delete()` Check the return value before continuing with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are developing for Android M I guess? For Andorid M you have to get permissions on runtime.

Please look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Search for "Android M runtime permissions" and you will find thousands of examples and  explanations.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was the issue. Now I solved it.